# Using the result of NIntegrate as a potential in NDEigensysem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I am trying to find the eigenvalues and eigenstates of a Hamiltonian with a potential which cannot be analytically defined. In particular, it is the integral of the product between two functions:

```
V[r_,d_] := NIntegrate[Vint[r-s] X[s,d],{s,0,Infinity}]
```

where `Vint[r_]:=(r^2 - c^2)/(r^2 + c^2) 1/(r^2 + b^2)^2`  with `b=0.0023` and `c=0.4878`, and `X[s_,d_]:=1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] d) Exp[-(1/2) s^2/d^2]`

The integral seems to give no problem and I can successfully plot it as a function of `r`.
Nevertheless, when I try to put it inside `NDEigensystem` with a fixed value of `d`:

```
Sol = NDEigensystem[{-D[u[r], {r, 2}] + V[r, 0.1] u[r], u[R] == 0, 
u[0] == 0}, u[r], {r, 0, R}, 2, Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}];
```

I get two possible outputs depending on the value of `d`:

```
NIntegrate: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option.
```

or

```
NIntegrate: The integrand -((3.98942 E^(-<<18>> s^2) (-0.237949+(r-s)^2))/((5.29*10^-6+(r-s)^2)^2 (0.237949 +(r-s)^2))) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1.,0.}}.
```

Moreover, when I try to set a value for `MinRecursion` in the definition of `V`, I always get the second error.

Am I doing something wrong or it is just not possible to use such a function inside `NDEigensystem`?

Comment: Please provide the complete minimal problem, so that readers can  run it.  Also, it might be better to use different symbols for `V[r_,c_]` and `V[r-s]` to avoid possible confusion.  Also, try `V[r_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ]`.

Comment: What values of `d` are you using typically, and what value of `MinRecursion`?

Comment: I tried with d between 0.01 and 1. Sorry, I forgot to write that.

Comment: Values for `R` and `MaxRecursion`?

Comment: R is about 1000, and I did not specify any MaxRecursion. I also tried with ?NumericQ as you suggested but I get the second error again.

Comment: The eigenvalues are, to a good approximation, `(n Pi/R)^2`, but solving the problem numerically will be very slow.

Answer (score 7):

This seemingly simple problem is numerically challenging due to the diversity of scales involved, or order `R`, `d`, `b`, and

```
Sqrt[-(2 b^3 (b + c)^2)/((b^2 - 2 b c - c^2) π)]
```

To gain an understanding of problem, begin by plotting the potential, `V`.

```
Plot[V[r, .1], {r, 0, R}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, V}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Thus, there are two families of solutions, those trapped at the bottom of the deep well near `r = 0`, and those filling the entire range, `{0 , R}`.

As stated in the question, `V` is the integral of `Vint[r-s] X[s, d]`.  Plotting `Vint` shows that it is delta-function-like for small `b`.  Not surprizingly, `Nintegrate` encounters difficulties, unless `MaxRecursion` is very large.  This explains the first error message in the question.  The second error message may be due to a symbolic call by `NDEigensystem` to `V` during initialization.  In any case, redefining `V` as

```
V[r_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Vint[r - s] X[s, d], {s, 0, Infinity}]
```

is good practice.  The integral over the delta-function-like `Vint` is.

```
Integrate[(r^2 - c1^2)/(r^2 + c1^2)/(r^2 + b1^2)^2, {r, -Infinity, Infinity},
    Assumptions -> b1 > 0 && c1 > 0]

(* ((b1^2 - 2 b1 c1 - c1^2) π)/(2 b1^3 (b1 + c1)^2) *)
```

Now, first consider eigenfunctions trapped in the bottom of the well.  By trial and error, I found that `NDEigensystem` does not find those modes unless the minimum value of the potential is shifted to near zero (and the eigenvalues shift accordingly).  Solve

```
R = 0.02;
sol = NDEigensystem[{-D[u[r], {r, 2}] + (V[r, 0.1] - 
    1/(Sqrt[2 π] .1) ((b^2 - 2 b c - c^2) π)/(2 b^3 (b + c)^2)) u[r], u[R] == 0, 
    u[0] == 0}, u[r], {r, 0, R}, 2,   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> 
    {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> R 10^-2}}}];
%[[1]] + 1/(Sqrt[2 π] .1) ((b^2 - 2 b c - c^2) π)/(2 b^3 (b + c)^2)

(* {-5.10788*10^8, -5.10096*10^8} *)

Plot[Evaluate@sol[[2]], {r, 0, R}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, u}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Accurately computing solutions filling the range `{0, R}` is exceedingly slow using the code in the question.  However, using the `delta-function` approximation to `Vint` makes such computations practical.

```
Vdel[r_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := 
    Piecewise[{{X[r, d] ((b^2 - 2 b c - c^2) π)/(2 b^3 (b + c)^2), r < 3}}, 0]
```

(Underflow messages otherwise occur for large values of `r`.)

```
R = 1;
sol1 = NDEigensystem[{-D[u[r], {r, 2}] + Vdel[r, 0.1] u[r], u[R] == 0, u[0] == 0},
    u[r], {r, 0, R}, 2, Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> R 10^-6}}}];
%[[1]]

(* {37.7529, 150.994} *)

Plot[Evaluate@sol1[[2]], {r, 0, R}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, u}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

The exceeding small `MaxCellMeasure` is required to resolve rapid oscillations near the well.  For larger `R`, the wavelengths of the eigenfunctions away from the well become correspondingly longer, and the eigenfunctions approximated by `(n Pi/R)^2`, with `n` a positive integer.

Comment: May be of advantage to evaluate the potential analytically @bbgodfrey . `Vint[r_] = (r^2 - c^2)/(r^2 + c^2) 1/(r^2 + b^2)^2 /. {b -> 23/10000, 
       c -> 4878/10000} // Together // ExpandAll // Apart;

X[s_, d_] = 1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] d) Exp[-(1/2) s^2/d^2];

vxe = Vint[r - s] X[s, d] // Expand;
V[r_, d_] = 
 Integrate[#, {s, 0, Infinity}, 
      Assumptions -> {1/100 < d < 1, 0 < r < 1000}] & /@ vxe // 
   ComplexExpand[Re@#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
  Simplify[#, Assumptions -> {1/100 < d < 1, 0 < r < 1000}] & `

Comment: @Akku14  Very impressive.  This eliminates the first error message in the question.  By the way, I am surprised that each of the three terms in `vxe` must be integrated separately.